# fill column with value of a column from another dataframe, depending on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like this (my input database on COVID cases)

data:

```
    date      state  cases
0   20200625  NY     300
1   20200625  CA     250
2   20200625  TX     200
3   20200625  FL     100
5   20200624  NY     290
6   20200624  CA     240
7   20200624  TX     100
8   20200624  FL     80
...
```

worth noting that the "date" column in the above data is a number (not datetime)

I want to make it a timeseries like this (desired output), with dates as index and each state's COVID cases as columns

```
          NY     CA     TX     FL
20200625  300    250    200    100
20200626  290    240    100    80
...
```

As of now I managed to create only the scheleton of the output with the following code

```
states = ['NY', 'CA', 'TX', 'FL']
days = [20200625, 20200626]

columns = states
positives = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

i = 0
for day in days:
   positives.loc[i, "date"] = day
   i = i +1

positives.set_index('date', inplace=True)
positives= positives.rename_axis(None)
print(positives)
```

which returns:

```
             NY   CA   TX   FL
20200625.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
20200626.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

how can I get from the "data" dataframe the value of column "cases" when:

(i)  value in data["state"] = column header of "positives",

(ii) value in data["date"] = row index of "positives"

Comment: Use , `df.pivot('date', 'state', 'cases')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
df = df.set_index(['date', 'state']).unstack().reset_index()

# fix column names
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)

state               CA     FL     NY     TX
0      20200624  240.0    NaN  290.0    NaN
1      20200625  250.0  100.0  300.0  200.0
```

Later, to set index again we need to set the name explicitly, do:

```
df = df.set_index("")
df.index.name = "date"
```

Comment: awesome!! it works perfectly. Only remaining issue is that i get some labels above the column headers: https://imgur.com/onv6hct (in the image: date, positive [positive was the name of column with the values that now fill the df.. and state above the index! ) Any suggestion on how to clean it ?

Comment: thank you... how can I make the column with the date the new index now? I would have used `df.set_index('date', inplace=True)` but there is not title for that column anymore

Comment: I don't now if I'm doing something wrong... but this is what I get https://imgur.com/IIYEWAs

... I'm looking to have 1 single headers row with name of states (NY...), without "state" at the beginning and on the same row as "date". Sorry for the multiple questions, I really really really appreciate your help.

Comment: try set `df.columns.name = None`

Answer (score 2):

The transformation you are interested in is called a pivot. You can achieve this in Pandas as follows:

```
# Reproduce part of the data
data = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20200625, 20200625, 20200624, 20200624], 
                     'state': ['NY', 'CA', 'NY', 'CA'], 
                     'cases': [300, 250, 290, 240]})
data

#        date state  cases
# 0  20200625    NY    300
# 1  20200625    CA    250
# 2  20200624    NY    290
# 3  20200624    CA    240

# Pivot
data.pivot(index='date', columns='state', values='cases')

# state      CA   NY
# date              
# 20200624  240  290
# 20200625  250  300
```